# Why does my Fashion MNIST CNN model classify even simple greyscale images OUTSIDE of its dataset so poorly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist, multiclass-classification

I trained my Convolutional NN model using keras-tensorflow and the Fashion Mnist dataset in a pretty standard way following online tutorials. I got a training accuracy of 96% and val acc of 91%. However, when I use this model to predict the type of clothing from similar greyscale images from google, the predictions are terrible. For example, the following shirt is classified as a trouser:
[greyscale shirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Lbf.jpg)

Similarly, dresses are classified as shoes and so far, I haven't gotten a single correct classification of external greyscale images of clothing. How is this so, when the training and validation accuracies aren't particularly terrible (or are they?) ?

And yes, the image I'm uploading has been normalized, made into 28x28 pixels and converted to greyscale in the code just to be sure.

Here is my code:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_valid, y_valid) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()



# Reshape the input data to a 4D tensor 
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
X_valid = X_valid.reshape((X_valid.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))


# Normalize the input data to have values between 0 and 1
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_valid = X_valid / 255.0



# myCallback


# Remember to inherit from the correct class
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    # Define the method that checks the accuracy at the end of each epoch
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if logs.get('accuracy') >= 0.995:                 
                print("\nReached 99.5% accuracy so cancelling training!")
                
                # Stop training once the above condition is met
                self.model.stop_training = True
    pass
        
            
            


from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define the ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=10,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

# Flow the training and validation images in batches of 128
train_flow = datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128)
valid_flow = datagen.flow(X_valid, y_valid, batch_size=128)



# convolutional_model
def model():
    

    # Define the model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        
  keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
      
      
      
      
    ])


    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
        
    return model

# Instantiate the callback class
callbacks = myCallback()

# Train the model
history = model().fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks=[callbacks])



model().save('myModelName.h5')


import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

# Load the trained model
model = load_model('myModelName.h5')

# Define class labels
class_labels = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
                'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

# Prompt user to upload an image
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
 
  # Load and preprocess the image
  path = '/content/' + fn
  img = load_img(path, target_size=(28, 28), color_mode='grayscale')
  x = img_to_array(img)
  x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
  x = x.astype('float32') / 255

  # Make prediction
  prediction = model.predict(x)
  predicted_class = class_labels[np.argmax(prediction)]

  # Plot the image 
  pyplot.imshow(x[0], cmap='gray')
  pyplot.show()
  print(x.shape)

  # Print the predicted class
  print(f'The uploaded image is a {predicted_class}')
```

Comment: From what I can see at the moment, fashion MNIST always has a dark background and your image has a bright one. This may be enough to confuse your model. Could you try to color-invert your image so that the background is dark and the clothing is bright against it?

Comment: You saved a randomly initialized model, not the model you trained, no wonder all predictions are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your implementation.
Here you should not create a new model, but to save the trained one:
Instead of this:

```
history = model().fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks=[callbacks])
model().save('myModelName.h5')
```

Change to this:

```
model = model()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks=[callbacks])
model.save('myModelName.h5')
```

The second mistake is that the fashion mnist have inverted colors, so you need to inverse your testing images as well.

You can do this here:

```
for fn in uploaded.keys():
...
    x = x.astype('float32') / 255
    x = 1 - x
...
```